# VBA - Create Dynamic Variable from different strings

Tags: vba, loops, variables

I'm a beginner on VBA. I have been following SO for years but have never really posted. I'm really struggling to understand a concept and have found no answers elsewhere.I want to  use a for loop  that 's going to  loop these three arrays going like the following:

```
EUR_Buy = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
USD_BUY = (2,4,6,8,10,12)
GBP_BUY = (1,3,5,7,9,11)
curr = (EUR,USD,GBP)

For i = 0 To 2
For j = 0 To 5
If curr(i) & "_BUY" & (j) = 8

MsgBox Yes
End If
Next j
Next i
```

The only thing I get is the name of the variable (ex: Eur_Buy(0) but not the value of the value which would be "1". Any idea how I could get this? Would be very helpful).

Thanks a lot and please do not hesitate if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a string from pieces and then expect the runtime to use this as variable name.
If you have a list of names and associated values, you can use a `Collection` (or a `Dictionary`).

The following piece of code gives you the idea how to use them.

```
' Create collection and fill it with 3 elements, each holding an array of 6 values
Dim myVars As New Collection
' Elements are added to a collection with add <value>, <key>
myVars.Add Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), "EUR_Buy"
myVars.Add Array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12), "USD_BUY"
myVars.Add Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11), "GBP_BUY"

Dim curr as Variant
Dim j As Long
For Each curr In Array("EUR", "USD", "GBP")
    Dim key As String
    key = curr & "_BUY"
    ' You can access an element of a collection with it's key (name) or index.
    For j = 0 To 5
        If myVars(key)(j) = 5 Then Debug.Print curr, j, "Found 8 in " & key
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Nice intro demonstrating collection and `For` .. `Each` loop in array; posted alternative via jagged array + Enum statement. @FunThomas

Answer (score 0):

**Referencing an Array of arrays via `Enum` statement**

If you have to deal with a *greater number* of currencies, it can increase readibility to

- use an enumeration defined in the head of a code module and to
- reference an Array of arrays (aka jagged array) by these placeholder variables in the main code and which
- holds the individual currency arrays for its part; you may think it as sort of container.

```
Option Explicit         ' head of code module
Enum C                  ' Enum statement allows automatic increments (if no special assignments)
    [_Start] = -1
    EUR
    USD
    GBP
    LastElement = GBP    ' (re-)set to last currency (here GBP), if changed
End Enum
```

Note that you can easily insert or add other currencies without caring in further code for the actual number as `Enum` automatically increments the start element (if not assigned explicitly).

The following example code

- assigns the individual arrays (starting a little bit tricky with the "Name" of the array as string value, e.g. "EUR") to `buy()` serving as container array and
- executes a `Match` over all enumerated currencies eventually.

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    '1) define zero-based buy arrays referenced by Enum values (~> module top)
    Dim buy(C.LastElement)                           ' declare 0-based Array of arrays
    buy(C.EUR) = Array("EUR", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)      ' assign the individual arrays
    buy(C.USD) = Array("USD", 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)
    buy(C.GBP) = Array("GBP", 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11)
    '2) define a search value
    Dim srch As Variant
    srch = 5
    '3) find value 5
    Dim curr As Long
    For curr = 0 To C.LastElement
        Dim no As Variant
        no = Application.Match(srch, buy(curr), 0)   ' << Find ordinal element position
        If IsNumeric(no) Then                        ' check for valid findings only
            no = no - 1                              ' adjust counter as Match returns 1-based numbers
            '4) display result of individual sub-array buy(curr)
            Debug.Print _
                buy(curr)(0), _
                "index " & no, _
                "Found " & buy(curr)(no) & " in " & buy(curr)(0) & "_BUY"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Note that `Application.Match` always returns a 1-based position number (adjusted to the 0-based index by a `-1` subtraction) within the individual arrays or an Error if there is no finding at all; checking the `no` result by `IsNumeric` allows to get only valid findings.

**Results** in the VB Editor's immediate window would be displayed e.g. as follows:

```
EUR           index 5       Found 5 in EUR_BUY
GBP           index 3       Found 5 in GBP_BUY
```